# Solving linear systems in Maxima

Tags: math, matrix, linear-programming, discrete-mathematics, maxima

I'm trying to write a general solver for a linear system in Maxima using `linsolve(eqlist, varlist)`, but without having to explicitly specify the dimension of the problem.

This works, but fixes the dimension to 3:

`linsolve( [ eq[0],eq[1],eq[2] ], [ a[0],a[1],a[2] ])`

This doesn't:

```
solution(p):=(  
  array(eq,p+1), /* creating arrays of length p+1 */
  array(a,p+1),

  for i:0 thru p do (
    eq[i]: sum(binom(j+1,i)*a[j],j,i,p) = binom(p,i)
  ),

  linsolve(eq,a)
)
```

Any insight on how to get this to work?

---

*Background behind the problem*: this linear system arises when solving the finite summation of integer powers, i.e. the sum of finitely many squares, cubes, or general powers `p`.  Although the finite sum of squares is straightforward, the general solution is surprisingly complicated: a discussion can be found here: [Finite Summation by Recurrence Relations, Part 2](http://mathscitech.org/articles/finite-summations-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in Maxima, lists and arrays are NOT the same underlying object.

Arrays are more complex and a bit of mess to get working (as suggested [in this posting](http://www.math.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2008/010002.html) to the Maxima mailing list).

The problem goes away if we stay away from arrays and work with lists instead:

```
solution(p):= block([a, eq],        /* give subroutine variables local scope */
    v : makelist(a[i], i, 0, p),    /* create list of unknowns (0-indexed) */
   eq : makelist(sum(binom(j+1,i)*a[j],j,i,p) = binom(p,i), i, 0, p),  
                                    /* create list of equations (0-indexed) */
   linsolve(eq, v)
)
```